# how can i print the data of partitions from JDBC database parallel read

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, parallel-processing

hi i would like to print the data of partitions from postgre database in parallel read, but it doesn't work
I would like to know is it possible to print it? i googled for a longtime, but nothing came up

here is the code i tried:

```
Dataset<Row> df= spark.read().format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:postgresql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+db )
                      .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
                      .option("dbtable", sql)
                      .option("user", user)
                      .option("password", passwd)
                      .option("partitionColumn", "rownum")
                    .option("numPartitions", 10)
                    .option("lowerBound", 1)
                    .option("upperBound", 2000)
                      .load();

df.foreach(x->{System.out.println("row:"+x);}); --> error
```

here is the error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2053)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
```

Comment: Is `df.show(false)` not enough?

Comment: it doesn't work, either. do we have other method?

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? What do you exactly want to print?

Comment: i actually want to print each row of each partition. i solve the problem anyway. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilise the `df.foreachPartition` method in Apache Spark to print data from partitions of a PostgreSQL database table in parallel. You probably tried to run a Spark job after the SparkContext had been stopped, which is why you got the error java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown." By using `foreachPartition` to loop over each partition of the DataFrame and print the data in parallel, the modified code supplied below resolves this problem:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachPartitionFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + db)
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    .option("dbtable", sql)
    .option("user", user)
    .option("password", passwd)
    .option("partitionColumn", "rownum")
    .option("numPartitions", 10)
    .option("lowerBound", 1)
    .option("upperBound", 2000)
    .load();

df.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>) iterator -> {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("row: " + row);
    }
});
```

Printing the PostgreSQL data without running into SparkContext shutdown-related problems is made possible by this code's effective parallel processing of data within each partition. Before running this code, make sure Spark is running and check your configuration to make sure Spark is initialising properly.

Hope this helps you, hit me up if you wanna know more

Comment: thank you! It found the error that i actually wrote "spark.stop()" before that code. it helps a lot